# How would I go about referencing a document type with RDFa?

Tags: semantic-web, schema.org, semantic-markup, rdfa

For a website, I need structured data for a ***publication*** content type. On this website, a *publication* is made of:

- a title
- a short description
- a date
- a category
- a URL to a document

---

1. What vocabulary should I use from Schema.org for such a content? (I thought about using *Article*)
2. I also would like to have a reference to the type of the linked document (PDF, Word, etc.). Is it a good idea to do so, and if yes, what property could I use for that?

Answer (score 2):

1. A good starting point is to look at http://schema.org/docs/full.html and search for a few types that might be relevant. See for example http://schema.org/PublicationIssue and http://schema.org/PublicationVolume in case they fit. Otherwise Article seems like a good type to start with. What kind of publications are you talking about?
2. I don't think that's possible today, I don't know of any property for this specific purpose. I would recommend that you ask this request on the schema.org mailing list so that it gets considered for addition, if you think it would be useful for your use case.

Comment: Yes I saw those 2 types but I don't think they really fit. What kind of publications? Well, it's a website about economy and every few days they publish some sort of reports, articles and other documents, most of the time as PDF. What I did for now is I used the `Article` and used the `url` property to reference the document. But as I said, there is a content on the website (Drupal) with a title, intro, date, etc. and a link to the document. What is unclear to me is whether the `url` should be used to reference the URL of the node itself or if it can be used to reference the linked PDF.